# Gmail API - How to Request Only one Name/Value Pair from Email Payload Headers?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

How can we capture only the email address in an api response for the gmail API. The 
`fields` parameter is set to `payload/headers`, which returns way more data than we need in the response. 
All we need is the `value` from one `name/value` pair in the JSON response; for example

The full response as we have it now looks something like this

```
    {
     "payload": {
     "headers": [
                 {
                  "name": "Delivered-To",
                  "value": "xxxxxxx"
                {
                 "name": "Received",
                 "value": "xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                "name": "Received-SPF",
                "value": "----"
                 },......
                 {
                  "name": "To",
                  "value": "xxxxxxx" 
                 }, ...... E.T.C........E.T.C ......

  /*All we want is one name/value pair to be returned e.g. */
      {
        "payload": {
                 "headers": [
                   {
               "name": "X-Failed-Recipients",
               "value": "............."
               }
             ]
      }
```

A better question might be is there a better way to capture bounced/returned mail than this via the gmail API?

Also, is it possible to request an XML response instead of JSON. How can that be done for the gmail API?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

You can do messages.get(format=METADATA, metadataIncludeHeaders=["To", "From", "Subject"]) for example, now to just request the specific headers you care about .  Note this only works with the metadata format (it won't include the body also, if you want all the body you get the full email.  Based on the list of headers, shouldn't be too hard to turn that into a map/dict of key => [list, of, values].

As to your second question, yes you can definitely request response in any format you want.  That's a standard Google API question though.  I can't find a good reference (surely some searching will) but typically you can set an "alt=xml" or "alt=" query parameter to get response in that format.  Not sure how this is exposed in any particular client library.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your [message payload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload) and then you want to use the `getall` method to return a list of headers and then you can use the `getitem` to pull any specific header you want from that list.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the String into a String and took it as a JSON Array and iterated through it to take the JSON Object that I required.

```
private static DirtyMail getHeaderParts(DirtyMail mail, List<MessagePartHeader> headers)
             {
                 try {
                     //Convert the header into JSON Array for easy processing of data.
                     JSONArray headerArray = new JSONArray(headers.toString());
                     for(int n = 0; n < headerArray.length() ; n++) {
                         JSONObject jsonObject = headerArray.getJSONObject(n);

                         //Pull date
                         if(jsonObject.get(Constants.DATE)!=null) {
                            mail.setDate(jsonObject.getString(Constants.DATE));
                         }

                         //Pull Subject

                         //Pull reply-to address

                         //Pull delivered-from address

                         //Pull delivered-to address

                         Log.d(TAG, "JSON Object : "+ jsonObject);
                     }
                     //Log.d(TAG,"header String: "+headers.toString());
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

        return mail;
    }
```

I kept these values in the Constant class :

```
// Data pulled from inside the header
    public static final String DATE = "Date";
    public static final String SUBJECT = "Subject";
    public static final String REPLY_TO = "Reply-To";
    public static final String DELIVERED_TO = "Delivered-To";
    public static final String FROM = "From";
```

I don't know if this is the best fix for this, but this works and gives the data as I require.